# How to display content on modal from database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, jsp, modal-dialog

I am trying to display comments on the modal for different posts. When I click the comment button of first post. It shows the comments related to that post but for second post when I click comment button it is showing the comments of first post.

Here is the code

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<!-- Modal content -->
<div id="myC" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <%
                PreparedStatement ps2 = null;
                ResultSet rs2 = null;
                String sql2 = "select * from comment where post_id=? ";
                ps2 = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
                ps2.setInt(1, rs.getInt("post_id"));
                rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();
                while (rs2.next()) {
            %>
            <p style="background-color: #e3f2fd; padding: 10px; margin: 10px;" id="com" ><%= rs2.getString("comment")%></p> 
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $(".c").click(function() {
                        $("#myC").modal('show');
                        var com = document.getElementById("com");
                        com.textContent = this.content;
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <%           }

            %>

            <p id="print" ></p>
            <textarea class="comment" name="comment" id="comment" style="padding: 10px; margin: 5px; "></textarea><br>
            <!--<a href="AddComment.jsp?to_user=">-->
            <input type="hidden" value="<%=rs.getInt("post_id")%>" name="post_id" id="post_id">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" style="width: 50%; margin-bottom : 12px; margin-left: 120px;" onclick="loadAjax()">Post Comment</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I use loadAjax() method to store the comments in database without  refreshing the page.

'''

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

                            function loadAjax() {
                                var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;
                                var post_id = document.getElementById("post_id").value;
                                //                                                if (username.trim() == "" || email.trim() == "" || topic.trim() == "" || comment.trim() == "") {
                                //                                                    alert("All fields are Required");
                                //                                                    return false;
                                //                                                }


                                var url = "AddComment.jsp?post_id=" + post_id + "&comment=" + comment;



                                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

                                    request = new XMLHttpRequest();

                                } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {

                                    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                                }
                                try {
                                    request.onreadystatechange = sendInfo;
                                    request.open("POST", url, true);
                                    request.send();

                                } catch (e) {
                                    document.write(e);
                                }
                            }

                            function sendInfo() {
                                var p = document.getElementById("print");

                                if (request.readyState == 1) {
                                    var text = request.responseText;
                                    p.innerHTML = "Please Wait...";
                                    console.log("1");
                                }

                                if (request.readyState == 2) {
                                    var text = request.responseText;
                                    console.log("2");
                                }
                                if (request.readyState == 3) {
                                    var text = request.responseText;
                                    console.log("3");
                                }
                                if (request.readyState == 4) {
                                    var text = request.responseText;
                                    p.innerHTML = text;
                                }
                            }
                        </script>
```

'''
AddComment.jsp :

```
<%@page import="dao.Methods"%>
<%@page import="myconnection.MyCon"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import ="java.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Add Comment</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <%
                String comment = request.getParameter("comment");
                int post_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("post_id"));
                HttpSession session2 = request.getSession();
                int by_user= Integer.parseInt(session2.getAttribute("user_id").toString());
                try {
                    Methods method = new Methods();
                    if (method.addComment(by_user, post_id, comment)) {

            %>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <%=comment%>
                </strong>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <%
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.println(e);
        }
    %>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does `loadAjax()` has in it ? Post that as well

Comment: I have edited the post.

Comment: Okay what is  `.c` ? which you have use in click event ?How are comments display that first code is for modal ? From where user click ?

Comment: I have used .c to open comment modal

Comment: <a herf="uhi.jsp" id="<%= rs.getInt("post_id")%>" class="c" ><button id="cBtn" class="btn btn-dark "  >View Comments</button></a>

Comment: Okay there are mutliple such buttons ? and here `<%= rs.getInt("post_id")%>` is id which you need .. Also is ok if you use ajax here because you cannot pass that value directly inside query  either you need to submit it or use ajax?

Comment: no there is one comment button for each jumbotron and i am using post_id to display the comments.